# If a directory is a file, can I see the contents of that file?

Tags: filesystems, directory

If a directory is a special file in unix with filenames and corresponding inodes, is there any way to print the entire contents of this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well do it just by 
Vim

Comment: if I do `vim <directory` what shows up is a list of contents, but there isn't any inodes. Isn't the directory file supposed to show corresponding inodes?

Comment: ls -id /path/to/dir

Comment: I know I can do that if I'm just trying to determine the inodes, but I'm really trying to gain a better understanding of the filesystem. If I read the entire contents of a directory file, shouldn't part of that be the inodes?

Comment: actually not getting what output you are looking for

Comment: I understand the confusion, I'm not looking for particular data, for any particular purpose. I just read that in Unix, a directory is actually a file which has file names and corresponding inodes inside it.  So I wanted to print the entire contents of the directory "file" to see what else it might have inside and what it looks like.

Comment: i guess the command you are looking for is  stat , looking into it man page you all get load of information , see if it helps you , try various switch mentioned in man pages of stat , else we ll dig further

Comment: @Jake I don't think it's really guaranteed to be a file, you just can think of it as a file with such entries but how exactly it's done one FS level is not defined. Far from an expert on this though, I have no idea how the API for this looks like.